# Writing Django forms and views

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

Is it right to write  django forms inside views.py or should i keep 2 separate files

- views.py
- forms.py

Which is the right convention ? I have seen different projects following these two convensions

Comment: For any reasonable length project whatsoever, the views.py tends to get messy in and of itself. It would be better, in my opinion, to modularize as much as possible, for both: a cleaner codebase, as well as your own sanity.

Comment: @itsme did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: @rnevius Yup. Sorry for the delay.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "right" here. Forms can be defined in either **views.py** or **forms.py** (calling it "forms.py" is merely a naming convention that has been widely adopted). It really comes down to personal preference.

Larger projects will likely benefit by keeping forms separate (if only to keep things less cluttered).